# Using syscalls to read files - is this bad?

Tags: c, unix, posix

I have some (presumably stable) legacy C code that uses POSIX system calls to read binary files. It's nothing more than `creat()`, `read()`, and `write()`. The program doesn't sit close to the metal at all (it loads string data into memory), so it seems wrong that it's using syscalls. I think I can refactor it easily to use more standard functions.

But, given that my code doesn't need to be portable, I can't think of a good reason to rewrite it. Am I missing something, or should I leave the code be?

Comment: If it ain't broke, don't fix it.

Comment: Since when are these `syscalls`?  here is the synopsis for a `syscall()`:   #define _GNU_SOURCE         /* See feature_test_macros(7) */
       #include <unistd.h>
       #include <sys/syscall.h>   /* For SYS_xxx definitions */

       int syscall(int number, ...);   Note: the `...` is a variable list of parameters for the called function

Comment: @user3629249: they *are* listed *in* [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) so the OP is right in calling them system calls (at least on Linux; AFAIK POSIX don't speak of system calls)

Comment: @William: why do you think it is wrong to use syscalls? It is often the right thing to do...

Comment: How do you think fopen works?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, of-course you must get rid of those terrible low-level syscalls. And while you are at it, you should also get rid of that terrible low-level language called C.
<sarcasm off>

On a more serious note and based on the principle of [YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren't_gonna_need_it), unless *you* have a clear need to change your use of syscalls to something else, doing it is only a waste of effort.

The primary reason for not using those syscalls is because you would need portability to non-posix systems, but you already stated that that is not the case for you.